# How to specific "Always redirect to external provider when login" in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When I want to login via Facebook for example for the first time, everything works. But, after a logout and an attempt to re-login in the same provider, redirection does not occur, and the system logs in using the previous account. How to specify "Always redirect"?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    // read external identity from the temporary cookie
    var result =
        await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }

    // lookup our user and external provider info
    var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = await FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
    // retrieve return URL
    var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = await AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);
    }

    if (user.Email == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EnterEmail", new { provider, providerUserId, returnUrl });
    }

    var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
    var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
    ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
    // issue authentication cookie for user
    var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    additionalLocalClaims.AddRange(principal.Claims);
    var name = principal.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? user.Id;
    
    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
    {
        DisplayName = name,
        IdentityProvider = provider,
        AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);

    // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    
    // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.Id, name, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

    if (context != null)
    {
        if (context.IsNativeClient())
        {
            // The client is native, so this change in how to
            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);
        }
    }

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Logout:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
    var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);
    vm.TriggerExternalSignout = true;
    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        // delete local authentication cookie
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        // raise the logout event
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
    }
    else
    {
        vm.TriggerExternalSignout = false;
    }
    // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
    if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
    {
        // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
        // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
        // complete our single sign-out processing.
        string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

        // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
    }

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

I tried clear cookie, but nothing changed. Then, i tried specify "prompt":"login" in AuthentificationProperties - noting changed.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't redirect? My guess is it could redirect but since you are already signed with Facebook, it just logs you in silently. Note that logging out of your app doesn't log you out of Facebook

Comment: Yes, you're right, it redirect. But how to logout of Facebook when i logout of my app?

Comment: Just what if i wanna choose different account on Facebook to login in my app?

Comment: You can't. Facebook doesn't support federated sign out as far as I know

Comment: I'd be glad to know if it changed